# User posting spammy links

Tags: discussion, spam

[This user](https://serverfault.com/users/53600/user53600) seems to do nothing but post links to recoverytoolbox.com. They have made several identical posts pointing to the same software, depending on the question they're answering.

It's not massive amounts of spam, but the broken English spammy links are getting somewhat irritating now.

Answer (score 3):

Flag, flag, flag, flag flag and then

[image]